# how can i make a correct regex in django?

Tags: python, regex, django

I need to make regex to make a button witch put me on other website

this is my re_path:

```
re_path (r'^detaletournament(?P<turnament_id>[0-9]+)/$',detaletournament)
```

Using the URLconf defined in projekt.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
tir
login
register
usertournaments
turnament
addturnament
takepart
deletetournament
quittournament
mytournaments
webturnament
profile
^detaletournament(?P<turnament_id>[0-9]+)/$
```

The current path, detaletournament, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Can you provide the URL that did not work?

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/detaletournament/(?P%3Cturnament_id%3E(%5Cd)+)/$
Using the URLconf defined in projekt.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
tir
login
register
usertournaments
turnament
addturnament
takepart
deletetournament
quittournament
mytournaments
webturnament
profile
^detaletournament/(?P<turnament_id>(\d)+)/$
The current path, detaletournament/(, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably meant for the regex to be `r'^detaletournament/(?P<turnament_id>[0-9]+)/$'` (note the added / )
2. The URL you should try is then detaletournament/5/ for example, you just tried the regular expression itself as a URL and that doesn't work, because it expects a number.